# Let's clean up [lang]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag wiki for [lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lang) states:

> Any HTML element may have a lang attribute with a value from the IETF's "BCP 47" list of language codes. This tag is for questions about the attribute's usage; problems with specific browsers should add the relevant tag as well.

However, it's being used for

- Generic language-related questions (such as [CKFinder standalone .popup() setting language does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912217/ckfinder-standalone-popup-setting-language-does-not-work))
- [Go questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lang+go) due to "golang"
- General questions about programming languages (such as [What is the name of this unit-testing based method to learn coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893266/what-is-the-name-of-this-unit-testing-based-method-to-learn-coding))
- Questions that just happen to *use the word language* (such as [Put something in the middle of an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797830/put-something-in-the-middle-of-an-url))

[lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lang) seems reasonable enough, and I can imagine someone being an expert in that area. However, the questions with that tag are far too cluttered for this hypothetical expert to usefully follow the tag.

Comment: Not sure completely nuking it wouldn't be better, but have fun.